# The word Torah in the Psalms.

Tags: words, translation, tehilim-psalms

I was wondering if the word for torah is used anywhere in the Psalms. If so, can you please tell me where exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variations of the word in the Masoretic Text appear 222 times among 213 verses, [which include 36 instances within the Book of Psalms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63n8a.png).

The software used to make this analysis was the [Interlinear Scripture Analyzer](http://www.scripture4all.org/), which is free.

Comment: Note that the verse numbers in your list on the right are sometimes off by one (it uses Christian verse numbers).

Comment: @magicker72 - The software is careful to note [the verse numbering in the Masoretic Text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcbw8.png).

Answer (score 5):

The word "Torat" (the Torah OF) appears 3 times:
19:8
37:31
119:72

V'torah (AND the Torah)
78:5

B'Torat (IN the Torah of)
119:1

M'Torat'cha (FROM YOUR Torah)
119:51, 94:12, 119:150

Toratecha/Torat'cha (YOUR Torah)
119:53, 55, 70, 77, 92, 97, 136, 153, 163, 174

K'Toratech (according to your Torah)
119:85

(There might be more...my search method changed)

Answer (score 3):

78:5:

> וַיָּקֶם עֵדוּת בְּיַעֲקֹב **וְתוֹרָה** שָׂם בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל אֲשֶׁר צִוָּה אֶת אֲבוֹתֵינוּ לְהוֹדִיעָם לִבְנֵיהֶם

A tip of my hat to Double AA, who mentioned this verse in a comment on the question. The word appears in other places in Psalms also, including a whole bunch of times in 119.